# Yii TbButtonGroup wont work

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, yii

```
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
    'type'=>'success', 
    'buttons'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Action', 'url'=>'#'),
        array('items'=>array(
            array(
                'label'=>'set approved',
                'url'=>$this->createUrl('controller/dostuff'),
                'buttonType'=>'ajaxButton',
                'ajaxOptions'=>array(
                      'beforeSend' => 'function( request ) {
                          alert(request);
                        }'
                      ,
                      'success' => 'function( data ) {
                          alert(data);
                        }'
                      ,
                  ),
            ),
            array('label'=>'set blocked', 'url'=>'#', 'buttonType' => 'ajaxLink'),
            array('label'=>'set pending', 'url'=>'#', 'buttonType' => 'ajaxLink'),

        )),
    ),
)); ?>
```

I tried a lot but I cannot get this working.. I want to use yiis ajax behaviour on the first button of the buttongroup.. I dont even get javascript errors or anything.. just if I click the link it redirects me to the url - no ajax at all. Maybe you have an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in the TbButton file, see `run()` method:

```
public function run()
{
    echo $this->createButton();

    if ($this->hasDropdown())
    {
        $this->controller->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDropdown', array(
            'encodeLabel'=>$this->encodeLabel,
            'items'=>$this->items,
            'htmlOptions'=>$this->dropdownOptions,
        ));
    }
}
```

If the button contained in items, it will instance of TbDropdown, not TbButton; 
So `buttonType` and `ajaxOption` you tried to provide are useless.

You can choose another solution to replace this solution. You can set id for each item and write javascript to do ajax manualy.